# How to set qtRunResultsOptions.ResultsLocation to an ALM test set path

Tags: automation, vbscript, hp-uft

I'm working on an AOM to run my UFT scripts via .vbs files
I've seen some samples on how to set the Results location via local and temp path but for my goal, I want to set the Results Location on a specific Test Set inside alm.

I have already established ALM connection and manage to open a script that is inside ALM

Here's the portion of the code I am currently using and I want to modify:

```
' Prepare the RunResultsOptions object
    Set qtRunResultsOptions = CreateObject("QuickTest.RunResultsOptions") ' Create the Run Results Options object
    qtRunResultsOptions.ResultsLocation = "<TempLocation>" ' Set a temporary results location
```

I want to change the "TempLocation" into a specific Test Set path inside ALM. I'm wondering what would be the syntax and parameters needed.

Comment: Read the [official documentation](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/all/AutomationObjectModel/Content/QuickTest~RunResultsOptions~ResultsLocation.html) - "When working with a test in ALM, the results are saved using the values from the `TDRunName`, `TDTestInstance`, and `TDTestSet` properties.". So, use `<NewLocation>` in combination with those defined values instead of using `<Templocation>`.

Comment: Actually, I have also browsed the documentation, It's just unclear for me what would be the syntax when applied since there were no examples mentioned. It is much appreciated if you give me an example of the syntax. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/all/AutomationObjectModel/Content/QuickTest%7ERunResultsOptions.html) you need to use `<NewLocation>` and [set the three values](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/all/AutomationObjectModel/Content/QuickTest%7ERunResultsOptions%7EResultsLocation.html) `TDRunName`, `TDTestInstance`, and `TDTestSet`.

```
' Prepare the RunResultsOptions object
Set qtRunResultsOptions = CreateObject("QuickTest.RunResultsOptions") ' Create the Run Results Options object
qtRunResultsOptions.TDRunName = "..."
qtRunResultsOptions.TDTestInstance = "..."
qtRunResultsOptions.TDTestSet = "..."
'The above values must be set to generate a test path.
qtRunResultsOptions.ResultsLocation = "<NewLocation>"
```

<sup>*Code is provided untested*</sup>
<sup><sup>...</sup> *Denotes required information*</sup>

Comment: Hi, It seems working now. Thanks a lot for this! To add some info, TDTestSet should be in this path format : [ALM] Root\Test1\Test Set1